# Multiple checkboxes in jQuery mobile pop-up

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

http://jsfiddle.net/yptgdhqv/2/

Scroll to the last checkbox element in the pop-up and click. The focus stays on the first element, and the window is brought back to the top. Why is this happening? I have tried giving each checkbox/label unique IDs, that's not the issue.

Is this a bug in jQuery mobile 1.4.5? It doesn't happen in earlier versions.

Edit: This is apparently two separate issues. I don't care about the focus changing. But the window scrolling is a problem and happens no matter what kind of content is in the pop-up, whether it be checkboxes or just paragraph elements.

```
        <div data-role="content">
            <a href="#" data-role="button" id="test-button">Test popup</a>
            <div data-role="popup" id="confirmDialog" data-overlay-theme="a" data-theme="c" style="max-width:400px;" class="ui-corner-all">
                <div data-role="header" data-theme="a" class="ui-corner-top">
                  <h1>Delete Page?</h1>
                </div>
                <div data-role="content" data-theme="d" class="ui-corner-bottom ui-content">

                <form>

                    <label class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inherit ui-btn-icon-left ui-checkbox-off">Housing<input type="checkbox"> </label>
                    <label class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inherit ui-btn-icon-left ui-checkbox-off">Housing<input type="checkbox"> </label>
                    <label class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inherit ui-btn-icon-left ui-checkbox-off">Housing<input type="checkbox"> </label>
                    <label class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inherit ui-btn-icon-left ui-checkbox-off">Housing<input type="checkbox"> </label>
                     <label class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inherit ui-btn-icon-left ui-checkbox-off">Housing<input type="checkbox"> </label>
                    <label class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inherit ui-btn-icon-left ui-checkbox-off">Housing<input type="checkbox"> </label>
                    <label class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inherit ui-btn-icon-left ui-checkbox-off">Housing<input type="checkbox"> </label>
                    <label class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inherit ui-btn-icon-left ui-checkbox-off">Housing<input type="checkbox"> </label>
                     <label class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inherit ui-btn-icon-left ui-checkbox-off">Housing<input type="checkbox"> </label>
                    <label class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inherit ui-btn-icon-left ui-checkbox-off">Housing<input type="checkbox"> </label>
                    <label class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inherit ui-btn-icon-left ui-checkbox-off">Housing<input type="checkbox"> </label>
                    <label class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inherit ui-btn-icon-left ui-checkbox-off">Housing<input type="checkbox"> </label>
                     <label class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inherit ui-btn-icon-left ui-checkbox-off">Housing<input type="checkbox"> </label>
                    <label class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inherit ui-btn-icon-left ui-checkbox-off">Housing<input type="checkbox"> </label>
                    <label class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inherit ui-btn-icon-left ui-checkbox-off">Housing<input type="checkbox"> </label>
                    <label class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inherit ui-btn-icon-left ui-checkbox-off">Housing<input type="checkbox"> </label>
                     <label class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inherit ui-btn-icon-left ui-checkbox-off">Housing<input type="checkbox"> </label>
                    <label class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inherit ui-btn-icon-left ui-checkbox-off">Housing<input type="checkbox"> </label>
                    <label class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inherit ui-btn-icon-left ui-checkbox-off">Housing<input type="checkbox"> </label>



                    <h3 class="ui-title">Are you sure you want to delete this page?</h3>
                  <p>This action cannot be undone.</p>
                  <a href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-rel="back" data-theme="c">Cancel</a>    
                  <a href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-rel="back" data-transition="flow" data-theme="b">Delete</a>  
                </div>
                </form>              
            </div>
        </div>

        <div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">

        </div>
    </div>   
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your Popup outside the Page and initialize it by code:

```
$(function(){
    $( "#confirmDialog" ).enhanceWithin().popup();
});
```

Here is the reference for external popups: [Using the same popup across multiple pages](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/popup-outside-multipage/)

BTW, be aware there are a lot of issues in your snippet, but i guess you are about to migrate from an older JQM version to 1.4.5 and you haven't adjusted yet the whole stuff...

Answer (score 0):

Y have a same probleme
set a

> data-role="popup"

in your content

add

> $( "#confirmDialog" ).enhanceWithin().popup();

in end 
and set a theme to the popup

```js
$('#index').live('pagebeforeshow',function(e,data){    
    $('#test-button').live('click', function(e) {
        $('#confirmDialog').css('overflow-y', 'scroll');        
        $('#confirmDialog').popup('open');
    });    
});

$('#confirmDialog').on({
  popupbeforeposition: function() {
    var maxHeight = $(window).height() - 30;
    $('#confirmDialog').css('max-height', maxHeight + 'px');
  }
})
$( "#confirmDialog" ).enhanceWithin().popup();






(function($, undefined ) {
  $.widget( "mobile.simpledialog2", $.mobile.widget, {
 options: {
  version: '1.0.1-2012061300', // jQueryMobile-YrMoDaySerial
  mode: 'blank', // or 'button'
  themeDialog: 'b',
  themeInput: false,
  themeButtonDefault: false,
  themeHeader: 'a',
  
  fullScreen: false,
  fullScreenForce: false,
  dialogAllow: false,
  dialogForce: false,
  
  headerText: false,
  headerClose: false,
  buttonPrompt: false,
  buttonInput: false,
  buttonInputDefault: false,
  buttonPassword: false,
  blankContent: false,
  blankContentAdopt: false,
  
  resizeListener: true,
  safeNuke: true,
  forceInput: true,
  showModal: true,
  animate: true,
  transition: 'pop',
  clickEvent: 'click',
  zindex: '500',
  width: '280px',
  left: false,
  top: false,
  
  callbackOpen: false,
  callbackOpenArgs: [],
  callbackClose: false,
  callbackCloseArgs: []
 },
 _eventHandler: function(e,p) {
  // Handle the triggers
  var self = e.data.widget,
   o = e.data.widget.options;
  
  if ( ! e.isPropagationStopped() ) {
   switch (p.method) {
    case 'close':
     self.close();
     break;
    case 'html':
     self.updateBlank(p.source);
     break;
   }
  }
 },
 _create: function () {
  var self = this,
   o = $.extend(this.options, this.element.jqmData('options')),
   initDate = new Date(),
   content = $("<div class='ui-simpledialog-container ui-overlay-shadow ui-corner-all ui-simpledialog-hidden " + 
     ((o.animate === true) ? o.transition : '') + " ui-body-" + o.themeDialog + "'></div>");
   
  if ( o.themeButtonDefault === false ) { o.themeButtonDefault = o.themeDialog; }
  if ( o.themeInput === false ) { o.themeInput = o.themeDialog; }
  $.mobile.sdCurrentDialog = self;
  if ( typeof $.mobile.sdLastInput !== 'undefined' ) { delete $.mobile.sdLastInput; }
  self.internalID = initDate.getTime();
  self.displayAnchor = $.mobile.activePage.children('.ui-content').first();
  if ( self.displayAnchor.length === 0 ) { self.displayAnchor = $.mobile.activePage; }
  
  self.dialogPage = $("<div data-role='dialog' data-theme='" + o.themeDialog + "'><div data-role='header'></div><div data-role='content'></div></div>");
  self.sdAllContent = self.dialogPage.find('[data-role=content]');
  
  content.appendTo(self.sdAllContent);
  
  self.sdIntContent = self.sdAllContent.find('.ui-simpledialog-container');
  self.sdIntContent.css('width', o.width);
  
  if ( o.headerText !== false || o.headerClose !== false ) {
   self.sdHeader = $('<div style="margin-bottom: 4px;" class="ui-header ui-bar-'+o.themeHeader+'"></div>');
   if ( o.headerClose === true ) {
    $("<a class='ui-btn-left' rel='close' href='#'>Close</a>").appendTo(self.sdHeader).buttonMarkup({ theme  : o.themeHeader, icon   : 'delete', iconpos: 'notext', corners: true, shadow : true });
   }
   $('<h1 class="ui-title">'+((o.headerText !== false)?o.headerText:'')+'</h1>').appendTo(self.sdHeader);
   self.sdHeader.appendTo(self.sdIntContent);
  }
  
  if ( o.mode === 'blank' ) {
   if ( o.blankContent === true ) {
    if ( o.blankContentAdopt === true ) {
     o.blankContent = self.element.children();
    } else {
     o.blankContent = self.element.html();
    }
   }
   $(o.blankContent).appendTo(self.sdIntContent);
  } else if ( o.mode === 'button' ) {
   self._makeButtons().appendTo(self.sdIntContent);
  }
  
  self.sdIntContent.appendTo(self.displayAnchor.parent());
  
  self.dialogPage.appendTo( $.mobile.pageContainer )
   .page().css('minHeight', '0px').css('zIndex', o.zindex);
   
  if ( o.animate === true ) { self.dialogPage.addClass(o.transition); }
  
  self.screen = $("<div>", {'class':'ui-simpledialog-screen ui-simpledialog-hidden'})
   .css('z-index', (o.zindex-1))
   .appendTo(self.displayAnchor.parent())
   .bind(o.clickEvent, function(event){
    if ( !o.forceInput ) {
     self.close();
    }
    event.preventDefault();
   });

  if ( o.showModal ) { self.screen.addClass('ui-simpledialog-screen-modal'); }
  
  $(document).bind('simpledialog.'+self.internalID, {widget:self}, function(e,p) { self._eventHandler(e,p); });
 },
 _makeButtons: function () {
  var self = this,
   o = self.options,
   buttonHTML = $('<div></div>'),
   pickerInput = $("<div class='ui-simpledialog-controls'><input class='ui-simpledialog-input ui-input-text ui-shadow-inset ui-corner-all ui-body-"+o.themeInput+"' type='"+((o.buttonPassword===true)?"password":"text")+"' value='"+((o.buttonInputDefault!==false)?o.buttonInputDefault.replace( '"', "&#34;" ).replace( "'", "&#39;" ):"")+"' name='pickin' /></div>"),
   pickerChoice = $("<div>", { "class":'ui-simpledialog-controls' });
   
  
  if ( o.buttonPrompt !== false ) {
   self.buttonPromptText = $("<p class='ui-simpledialog-subtitle'>"+o.buttonPrompt+"</p>").appendTo(buttonHTML);
  }
  
  if ( o.buttonInput !== false ) {
   $.mobile.sdLastInput = "";
   pickerInput.appendTo(buttonHTML);
   pickerInput.find('input').bind('change', function () {
    $.mobile.sdLastInput = pickerInput.find('input').first().val();
    self.thisInput = pickerInput.find('input').first().val();
   });
  }
  
  pickerChoice.appendTo(buttonHTML);
  
  self.butObj = [];
  
  $.each(o.buttons, function(name, props) {
   props = $.isFunction( props ) ? { click: props } : props;
   props = $.extend({
    text   : name,
    id     : name + self.internalID,
    theme  : o.themeButtonDefault,
    icon   : 'check',
    iconpos: 'left',
    corners: 'true',
    shadow : 'true',
    args   : [],
    close  : true
   }, props);
   
   self.butObj.push($("<a href='#'>"+name+"</a>")
    .appendTo(pickerChoice)
    .attr('id', props.id)
    .buttonMarkup({
     theme  : props.theme,
     icon   : props.icon,
     iconpos: props.iconpos,
     corners: props.corners,
     shadow : props.shadow
    }).unbind("vclick click")
    .bind(o.clickEvent, function() {
     if ( o.buttonInput ) { self.sdIntContent.find('input [name=pickin]').trigger('change'); }
     var returnValue = props.click.apply(self, $.merge(arguments, props.args));
     if ( returnValue !== false && props.close === true ) {
      self.close();
     }
    })
   );
  });
  
  return buttonHTML;
 },
 _getCoords: function(widget) {
  var self = widget,
   docWinWidth   = $.mobile.activePage.width(),
   docWinHighOff = $(window).scrollTop(),
   docWinHigh    = $(window).height(),
   diaWinWidth   = widget.sdIntContent.innerWidth(),
   diaWinHigh    = widget.sdIntContent.outerHeight(),
   
   coords        = {
    'high'    : $(window).height(),
    'width'   : $.mobile.activePage.width(),
    'fullTop' : $(window).scrollTop(),
    'fullLeft': $(window).scrollLeft(),
    'winTop'  : docWinHighOff + ((widget.options.top !== false) ? widget.options.top : (( docWinHigh / 2 ) - ( diaWinHigh / 2 ) )),
    'winLeft' : ((widget.options.left !== false) ? widget.options.left : (( docWinWidth / 2 ) - ( diaWinWidth / 2 ) ))
   };
   
  if ( coords.winTop < 45 ) { coords.winTop = 45; }
   
  return coords;
 },
 _orientChange: function(e) {
  var self = e.data.widget,
   o = e.data.widget.options,
   coords = e.data.widget._getCoords(e.data.widget);
  
  e.stopPropagation();
  
  if ( self.isDialog === true ) {
   return true;
  } else {
   if ( o.fullScreen === true && ( coords.width < 400 || o.fullScreenForce === true ) ) {
    self.sdIntContent.css({'border': 'none', 'position': 'absolute', 'top': coords.fullTop, 'left': coords.fullLeft, 'height': coords.high, 'width': coords.width, 'maxWidth': coords.width }).removeClass('ui-simpledialog-hidden');
   } else {
    self.sdIntContent.css({'position': 'absolute', 'top': coords.winTop, 'left': coords.winLeft}).removeClass('ui-simpledialog-hidden');
   }
  }
 },
 repos: function() {
  var bsEvent = { data: {widget:this}, stopPropagation: function () { return true; }};
  this._orientChange(bsEvent);
 },
 open: function() {
  var self = this,
   o = this.options,
   coords = this._getCoords(this);
  
  self.sdAllContent.find('.ui-btn-active').removeClass('ui-btn-active');
  self.sdIntContent.delegate('[rel=close]', o.clickEvent, function (e) { e.preventDefault(); self.close(); });
  
  if ( ( o.dialogAllow === true && coords.width < 400 ) || o.dialogForce ) {
   self.isDialog = true;
   
   if ( o.mode === 'blank' ) { // Custom selects do not play well with dialog mode - so, we turn them off.
    self.sdIntContent.find('select').each(function () {
     $(this).jqmData('nativeMenu', true);
    });
   }
   
   self.displayAnchor.parent().unbind("pagehide.remove");
   self.sdAllContent.append(self.sdIntContent);
   self.sdAllContent.trigger('create');
   if ( o.headerText !== false ) {
    self.sdHeader.find('h1').appendTo(self.dialogPage.find('[data-role=header]'));
    self.sdIntContent.find('.ui-header').empty().removeClass();
   }
   if ( o.headerClose === true ) {
    self.dialogPage.find('.ui-header a').bind('click', function () {
     setTimeout("$.mobile.sdCurrentDialog.destroy();", 1000);
    });
   } else {
    self.dialogPage.find('.ui-header a').remove();
   }
   
   self.sdIntContent.removeClass().css({'top': 'auto', 'width': 'auto', 'left': 'auto', 'marginLeft': 'auto', 'marginRight': 'auto', 'zIndex': o.zindex});
   $.mobile.changePage(self.dialogPage, {'transition': (o.animate === true) ? o.transition : 'none'});
  } else {
   self.isDialog = false;
   self.selects = [];
   
   if ( o.fullScreen === false ) {
    if ( o.showModal === true && o.animate === true ) { self.screen.fadeIn('slow'); }
    else { self.screen.removeClass('ui-simpledialog-hidden'); }
   }
   
   self.sdIntContent.addClass('ui-overlay-shadow in').css('zIndex', o.zindex).trigger('create');
   
   if ( o.fullScreen === true && ( coords.width < 400 || o.fullScreenForce === true ) ) {
    self.sdIntContent.removeClass('ui-simpledialog-container').css({'border': 'none', 'position': 'absolute', 'top': coords.fullTop, 'left': coords.fullLeft, 'height': coords.high, 'width': coords.width, 'maxWidth': coords.width }).removeClass('ui-simpledialog-hidden');
   } else {
    self.sdIntContent.css({'position': 'absolute', 'top': coords.winTop, 'left': coords.winLeft}).removeClass('ui-simpledialog-hidden');
   }
   
   $(document).bind('orientationchange.simpledialog', {widget:self}, function(e) { self._orientChange(e); });
   if ( o.resizeListener === true ) {
    $(window).bind('resize.simpledialog', {widget:self}, function (e) { self._orientChange(e); });
   }
  }
  if ( $.isFunction(o.callbackOpen) ) {
   o.callbackOpen.apply(self, o.callbackOpenArgs);
  }
 },
 close: function() {
  var self = this, o = this.options, retty;
  
  if ( $.isFunction(self.options.callbackClose) ) {
   retty = self.options.callbackClose.apply(self, self.options.callbackCloseArgs);
   if ( retty === false ) { return false; }
  }
  
  if ( self.isDialog ) {
   $(self.dialogPage).dialog('close');
   self.sdIntContent.addClass('ui-simpledialog-hidden');
   self.sdIntContent.appendTo(self.displayAnchor.parent());
   if ( $.mobile.activePage.jqmData("page").options.domCache != true && $.mobile.activePage.is(":jqmData(external-page='true')") ) {
    $.mobile.activePage.bind("pagehide.remove", function () {
     $(this).remove();
    });
   }
  } else {
   if ( self.options.showModal === true && self.options.animate === true ) {
    self.screen.fadeOut('slow');
   } else {
    self.screen.addClass('ui-simpledialog-hidden');
   }
   self.sdIntContent.addClass('ui-simpledialog-hidden').removeClass('in');
   $(document).unbind('orientationchange.simpledialog');
   if ( self.options.resizeListener === true ) { $(window).unbind('resize.simpledialog'); }
  }
  
  if ( o.mode === 'blank' && o.blankContent !== false && o.blankContentAdopt === true ) {
   self.element.append(o.blankContent);
   o.blankContent = true;
  }
  
  if ( self.isDialog === true || self.options.animate === true ) {
   setTimeout(function(that) { return function () { that.destroy(); };}(self), 1000);
  } else {
   self.destroy();
  }
 },
 destroy: function() {
  var self = this,
   ele = self.element;
  
  if ( self.options.mode === 'blank' ) {
   $.mobile.sdCurrentDialog.sdIntContent.find('select').each(function() {
    if ( $(this).data('nativeMenu') == false ) {
     $(this).data('selectmenu').menuPage.remove();
     $(this).data('selectmenu').screen.remove();
     $(this).data('selectmenu').listbox.remove();
    }
   });
  }
  
  $(self.sdIntContent).remove();
  $(self.dialogPage).remove();
  $(self.screen).remove();
  $(document).unbind('simpledialog.'+self.internalID);
  delete $.mobile.sdCurrentDialog;
  $.Widget.prototype.destroy.call(self);
  if ( self.options.safeNuke === true && $(ele).parents().length === 0 && $(ele).contents().length === 0 ) {
   ele.remove();
  }
 },
 updateBlank: function (newHTML) {
  var self = this,
   o = this.options;
   
  self.sdIntContent.empty();
   
  if ( o.headerText !== false || o.headerClose !== false ) {
   self.sdHeader = $('<div class="ui-header ui-bar-'+o.themeHeader+'"></div>');
   if ( o.headerClose === true ) {
    $("<a class='ui-btn-left' rel='close' href='#'>Close</a>").appendTo(self.sdHeader).buttonMarkup({ theme  : o.themeHeader, icon   : 'delete', iconpos: 'notext', corners: true, shadow : true });
   }
   $('<h1 class="ui-title">'+((o.headerText !== false)?o.headerText:'')+'</h1>').appendTo(self.sdHeader);
   self.sdHeader.appendTo(self.sdIntContent);
  }
  
  $(newHTML).appendTo(self.sdIntContent);
  self.sdIntContent.trigger('create');
  $(document).trigger('orientationchange.simpledialog');
 },
 _init: function() {
  this.open();
 }
  });
})( jQuery );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>jQM Complex Demo</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>    
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="index" data-theme="a">
        <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
            <h3>
                First Page
            </h3>
            
        </div>

        <div data-role="content"  data-role="popup">
            <a href="#" data-role="button" id="test-button">Test popup</a>
            <div data-role="popup" id="confirmDialog"   style="max-width:400px;" class="ui-corner-all" data-theme="a">
                <div data-role="header"  class="ui-corner-top">
                  <h1>Delete Page?</h1>
                </div>
                <div data-role="content"  class="ui-corner-bottom ui-content">
                  
                <form >
             
                    <label class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inherit ui-btn-icon-left ui-checkbox-off">Housing<input type="checkbox"> </label>
                    <label class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inherit ui-btn-icon-left ui-checkbox-off">Housing<input type="checkbox"> </label>
                    <label class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inherit ui-btn-icon-left ui-checkbox-off">Housing<input type="checkbox"> </label>
                    <label class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inherit ui-btn-icon-left ui-checkbox-off">Housing<input type="checkbox"> </label>
                     <label class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inherit ui-btn-icon-left ui-checkbox-off">Housing<input type="checkbox"> </label>
                    <label class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inherit ui-btn-icon-left ui-checkbox-off">Housing<input type="checkbox"> </label>
                    <label class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inherit ui-btn-icon-left ui-checkbox-off">Housing<input type="checkbox"> </label>
                    <label class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inherit ui-btn-icon-left ui-checkbox-off">Housing<input type="checkbox"> </label>
                     <label class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inherit ui-btn-icon-left ui-checkbox-off">Housing<input type="checkbox"> </label>
                    <label class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inherit ui-btn-icon-left ui-checkbox-off">Housing<input type="checkbox"> </label>
                    <label class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inherit ui-btn-icon-left ui-checkbox-off">Housing<input type="checkbox"> </label>
                    <label class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inherit ui-btn-icon-left ui-checkbox-off">Housing<input type="checkbox"> </label>
                     <label class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inherit ui-btn-icon-left ui-checkbox-off">Housing<input type="checkbox"> </label>
                    <label class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inherit ui-btn-icon-left ui-checkbox-off">Housing<input type="checkbox"> </label>
                    <label class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inherit ui-btn-icon-left ui-checkbox-off">Housing<input type="checkbox"> </label>
                    <label class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inherit ui-btn-icon-left ui-checkbox-off">Housing<input type="checkbox"> </label>
                     <label class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inherit ui-btn-icon-left ui-checkbox-off">Housing<input type="checkbox"> </label>
                    <label class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inherit ui-btn-icon-left ui-checkbox-off">Housing<input type="checkbox"> </label>
                    <label class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inherit ui-btn-icon-left ui-checkbox-off">Housing<input type="checkbox"> </label>
                    
                   
                    
                    <h3 class="ui-title">Are you sure you want to delete this page?</h3>
                  <p>This action cannot be undone.</p>
                  <a href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-rel="back" >Cancel</a>    
                  <a href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-rel="back" data-transition="flow" >Delete</a>  
                </div>
                </form>              
            </div>
        </div>

        <div  data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">

        </div>
    </div>   
</body>
</html>
```